# Intuitive explanation for $Area_{\text{sphere}}\times\ Area_{\text{cross-section}}=Area_{\text{major cap}}\times Area_{\text{minor cap}}$

Tags: geometry, intuition, area, spheres

A sphere and a plane intersect to produce a circular intersection and two spherical caps.

$S=$ surface area of sphere
$C=$ area of circular intersection
$A=$ surface area of major cap
$B=$ surface area of minor cap

I have discovered that:

> $$S\times C=A\times B$$

Proof:

> Let $r=$ radius of sphere, $h=$ height of major cap.
> Using the [formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCap.html) for the surface area of a spherical cap,
> $A\times B=2\pi rh\times 2\pi r(2r-h)=4\pi r^2\times \pi(r^2-(r-h)^2)=S\times C$

The simplicity of the result makes me wonder if there is an intuitive explanation. ([Here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/09/14/pythagoras-theorem/) is an example of an intuitive explanation of a geometric result.)

So my question is:

> Is there an intuitive explanation for the fact that $S\times C=A\times B$ ?