# Is pure 3-d (solid) geometry basically 2d?

Tags: geometry, soft-question, 3d

I recently got interested in "pure" geometry (i.e. that doesn't use equations with x,y,z). I did some fun 2-d stuff like a circle inscribed in a square with a smaller circle in the corner, then find the relative radii. 
I then did similar 3-d stuff (a sphere in a cube, with a smaller sphere in the corner). In solving I noticed that I first converted to 2-d, by looking at a plane through the diagonal, then solved. So I got the impression than in pure solid geometry, you finally just end up resorting to 2-d geometry. 
But I just watched  [Why slicing a cone gives an ellipse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQa_tWZmlGs) by 3Blue1Brown and they did a pure approach to a conic section. I loved it but, is that approach unusual? Or are there lots of 3-d problems that have a pure, non-2d, approach?

Comment: In high school I took a one semester course in solid geometry (no analytics).  It was the most boring high school math course I took - even though I got 98 as a course grade.  I am a retired mathematician and I never used anything from the course.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4485351/intuitive-explanation-for-area-textsphere-times-area-textcross-section) is an example of a 3D problem that, I think, does not have a 2D approach.

Comment: There are actually examples solving 2D problems using 3D space. For instance, the problem "There are three circles, draw the two common tangent lines to each pair of two circles and denote the intersection points of each pair $A, B, C$. Prove that $A,B,C$ lies on the same line". In planar 2D geometry this problem is not so easy but using 3D space geometry the result is trivial.